# Error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members AlamoFire with Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have tried many of solutions with no luck. I'm trying to pass my json data and return the users values.

**Model:**

```
import Foundation

class UserModel: NSObject {

var UserID: String!
var Name: String!

init(UserID: String, Name: String) {
    super.init()

    self.UserID = UserID
    self.Name = Name

}
}
```

**Fetch Function:**

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.com/api.php?PatientList") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let pinPost = "&Token=\(token)"
    request.httpBody = pinPost.data(using: .utf8)

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let datas = dict["Data"] as? NSArray {
                for data in datas {

                    let users = UserModel(UserID: data["PatientID"], Name: data["DisplayName"])

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get a error message of `Type 'Any' has no subscript members` no previous solution has worked and I can't figure it out.

[image]

```
 ["Response": 1, "Data": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600002624ae0>(
 <__NSArrayI 0x600002455f60>(
 {
DOB = "09/08/1987";
DisplayName = "Jesse Gray";
PatientID = "1575da84-864f-11e8-9bae-02bd535e30bc";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
if let datas = dict["Data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
```

instead of

```
if let datas = dict["Data"] as? NSArray {
```

as array elements are of type `Any` that can't be subscribted here `data["PatientID"]` and `data["DisplayName"]`

```
Alamofire.request("request").responseJSON { (response) in
    if let dict = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
        if let datas = dict["Data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for data in datas {
                if let id = data["PatientID"] as? Int , let name = data["DisplayName"] as? String {
                  let users = UserModel(UserID:id, Name: name)
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also consider using `Codable` to parse the response

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: [UserModel]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case data = "Data"
    }
}

struct UserModel: Codable {
    let patientID: Int
    let displayName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case patientID = "PatientID"
        case displayName = "DisplayName"
    }
}

Alamofire.request("request").responseData{ (response) in
    if let data = response.data  {

        do {
            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
            print(res.data)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

---

The correct is

> { "Data" : [{"DisplayName":"Jerry Smith","DOB":"09/08/1987"}] }

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try and use the `Codable` solution: `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})))`

Comment: then your json is invalid

Comment: I've added a photo of my json, Could you please take a look.

Comment: post it as string as i will let you know the correct

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to get that but this is what it looks like printed out in string format

Comment: see edit , also there is no **PatientID** key so replace it with **DOB**

Comment: Do I need to change my json? What changed?

Comment: according to your last edit add the key **DOB** to codable and leave the other 2 keys as they are

Comment: I've added `DOB` exactly like the other values but still get the error. I've even updated my code to show the fetch from url function.

Comment: Actually if the picture is your response json , then you have to edit it in backend it will never decode with this invalid content

Comment: What part of the content do I need to change in the json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187084/discussion-between-cody-host-and-sh-khan).